# Microsoft.Azure.Search SearchServiceClient.Indexes.Create throws an exception "The request is invalid"

Tags: c#, .net, azure, search

When calling Create on Microsoft Azure Search, Search Service Client Indexes an exception is thrown.
The exception is: "The request is Invalid".
This is a console app in C# using .Net Core  3.1.
There isn't much discussion on this on the web.
What am I doing wrong?

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly string searchServiceName = "mysearchservice";
    private static readonly string adminApiKey = "<<admin key here>>";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var serviceClient = CreateSearchServiceClient();
        CreateIndex(serviceClient);
    }

    private static void CreateIndex(SearchServiceClient ssc)
    {
        var definition = new Microsoft.Azure.Search.Models.Index()
        {
            Name = "hotels",
            Fields = FieldBuilder.BuildForType<Hotel>()
        };
        ssc.Indexes.Create(definition); // Throws
    }

    private static SearchServiceClient CreateSearchServiceClient()
    {
        SearchServiceClient serviceClient = 
           new SearchServiceClient(searchServiceName, 
             new SearchCredentials(adminApiKey));
        return serviceClient;
    }
}
 
public class Hotel 
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]
    [IsFilterable]
    public string HotelId { get; set; }

    [IsSearchable, IsSortable]
    public string HotelName { get; set; }

    [IsSearchable]
    [Analyzer(AnalyzerName.AsString.EnLucene)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

   
    [IsSearchable, IsFilterable, IsSortable, IsFacetable]
    public string Category { get; set; }

    [IsSearchable, IsFilterable, IsFacetable]
    public string[] Tags { get; set; }

    [IsSearchable, IsSortable, IsFacetable]
    public bool? ParkingIncluded { get; set; }


    public DateTimeOffset? LastRenovationDate { get; set; }

    [IsFilterable,IsSortable,IsFacetable]
    public double? Rating { get; set; }

    [IsFilterable, IsSortable]
    public GeographyPoint Location { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this problem in the past, it's related to the Json serializer and Geographypoint. The following code should work:

```
    Uri serviceEndpoint = new Uri($"https://{searchServiceName}.search.windows.net/");

    var adminClient = new SearchIndexClient(serviceEndpoint, new AzureKeyCredential(adminApiKey));

    JsonSerializerOptions serializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        Converters =
        {
            new MicrosoftSpatialGeoJsonConverter()
        },
        PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
    };
    SearchClientOptions clientOptions = new SearchClientOptions
    {
        Serializer = new JsonObjectSerializer(serializerOptions)
    };

    FieldBuilder fieldBuilder = new FieldBuilder
    {
        Serializer = clientOptions.Serializer
    };

    var definition = new SearchIndex(indexName)
    {
        Fields = fieldBuilder.Build(typeof(Hotel))
    };
    adminClient.CreateOrUpdateIndex(definition);
```

Answer (score 0):

Index fields must be a string. When I changed the type from `int` to `string`, it succeeded. In the exception, it was saying `MoveNext` in reference to the `HttpRequest`. The body had one element, and it contained the error clarification.